# JavaScript Get Percentage

Tags: javascript

I am having a issue trying to work out the remaining percentage between 2 numbers.

I have worked out how to get the current percentage by using the following function:

```
function GetPercentage(x,y){
    return ((x /y) * 100).toFixed(0);
}
```

The part I need help with is to get the remaining percentage.

For Example:

Lets say the maximum is 31 and I have a value of 1, how can I return the value 97%

Using my function above if I use GetPercentage(1,31) it would return 3.
However, I need help with the function to return 97.

I have tried using the following but doesn't seem to work.. I am guessing my Math isn't correct and hoping someone can correct me.

```
alert(GetPercentage(1,31) + "%" + " used. " + availablePercentage(5,31) + "% still available"); // trying to make it say: 3% used. 97% still available

    function GetPercentage(x,y){
        return ((x / y) * 100).toFixed(0);
    }

    function availablePercentage(x,y){
        return ((y-x)/100).toFixed(0);
    }
```

Comment: `function GetPercentage(x,y){
    return 100 - ((x /y) * 100).toFixed(0);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to subtract the number you're computing from 100.

```
function availablePercentage(x,y){
    return 100 - GetPercentage(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I have tried everything but that.. works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

I believe a suitable formula for what you are looking for is

```
((y - x) / y) * 100
```

so for the inputs `x = 1` and `y = 31` you would get

```
((31 - 1) / 31) * 100
(30 / 31) * 100
96.77
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you mean, given there are 31 things to do and I have done 1 what is the % that remain to do?

You need to subtract from 1 ( and multiply by 100 if you want percent from 0-100)

eg

```
function todoPercent(numTodo, numDone){
     return (1-numDONE/numTodo)*100;
}
```